# Text formats issues while creating PDF

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, footer, tcpdf

While using TCPDF I found some issues which are very weird to me but I was unable to solve them.
1) I am unable write a paragraph on the next page forcefully.
2) I am unable to write footer with multiline like

`Test | Test`
Test | Test

While using

```
$pdfOutput = 'First Page Para<br />Next Page Para<br />Last Page Para';

class MYPDF extends TCPDF {



        public function Footer() {
        $cur_y = $this->y;
        $this->SetTextColorArray($this->footer_text_color);
        //set style for cell border
        $line_width = (0.85 / $this->k);
        $this->SetLineStyle(array('width' => $line_width, 'cap' => 'butt', 'join' => 'miter', 'dash' => 0, 'color' => $this->footer_line_color));
        //print document barcode
        $barcode = $this->getBarcode();
        if (!empty($barcode)) {
            $this->Ln($line_width);
            $barcode_width = round(($this->w - $this->original_lMargin - $this->original_rMargin) / 3);
            $style = array(
                'position' => $this->rtl?'R':'L',
                'align' => $this->rtl?'R':'L',
                'stretch' => false,
                'fitwidth' => true,
                'cellfitalign' => '',
                'border' => false,
                'padding' => 0,
                'fgcolor' => array(0,0,0),
                'bgcolor' => false,
                'text' => false
            );
            $this->write1DBarcode($barcode, 'C128', '', $cur_y + $line_width, '', (($this->footer_margin / 3) - $line_width), 0.3, $style, '');
        }
        $w_page = isset($this->l['w_page']) ? $this->l['w_page'].' ' : '';
        if (empty($this->pagegroups)) {
            $pagenumtxt = $w_page.$this->getAliasNumPage().' / '.$this->getAliasNbPages();
        } else {
            $pagenumtxt = $w_page.$this->getPageNumGroupAlias().' / '.$this->getPageGroupAlias();
        }
        $this->SetY($cur_y);
        //Print page number
        if ($this->getRTL()) {
            $this->SetX($this->original_rMargin);
            $this->Cell(0, 0, $pagenumtxt, 'T', 0, 'L');
        } else {
            $this->SetX($this->original_lMargin);
            $this->Cell(0, 0, $this->getAliasRightShift().$pagenumtxt, 'T', 0, 'R');
        }
    }
}


$pdf = new MYPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetPrintHeader(false);

$pdf->SetHeaderData('', '', '', '');

$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

$pdf->SetMargins('25', PDF_MARGIN_TOP,'25');
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);


$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
    $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}

$pdf->SetFont('times', '', 12);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->writeHTML($pdfOutput, true, true, true, true, '');

$ReturnVal = $pdf->Output('Sample_PDF', 'I');
```